# Use javascript to breakup a HTML div item via separator

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I currently have a page with a gallery of images with captions on it.

```
<img>image1</img>
<div class="caption">IMAGE 1 TITLE: Subtitle</div>
<img>image2</img>
<div class="caption">IMAGE 2 TITLE: Subtitle</div>
```

and I would like to separate the `Image Title` from the `Subtitle` so that I can style them separately. They are always separated via a colon `:`. After replacement, the code should look something like

```
<img src="image1">
<div class="caption">
    <span class="title">IMAGE 1 TITLE</span>
    <span class="subtitle">Subtitle</span>
</div>
<img src="image2">
<div class="caption">
    <span class="title">IMAGE 2 TITLE</span>
    <span class="subtitle">Subtitle</span>
</div>
```

I do not have the ability to edit the HTML code, but I can do JS code injection and add custom CSS (this is a squarespace website).

I am looking for a script that would separate the text before and after the colon and wrap each of them in a class.

Comment: so you need to select the elements, loop over, read the textContent, split it, and set the innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the text, split it, and change the HTML to reflect your desired title/subtitle markup.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.caption').forEach((caption) => {
  const [title, subtitle] = caption.textContent.trim().split(/\s*:\s*/);
  caption.innerHTML = `
    <span class="title">${title}</span>
    <span class="subtitle">${subtitle}</span>
  `;
});
```

```css
.caption { color: blue; }

.title { font-weight: bold; }
.subtitle { font-style: italic; }

.title:after { content: ':'; } /* optional */
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/40" alt="image1" />
<div class="caption">IMAGE 1 TITLE: Subtitle</div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/80/60" alt="image2" />
<div class="caption">IMAGE 2 TITLE: Subtitle</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This script selects all the captions on the page using `document.querySelectorAll('.caption')`, loops through each caption, and then splits the text content of the caption into title and subtitle using the colon separator. It then creates a new HTML string with the title and subtitle wrapped in  tags with appropriate classes, and replaces the original caption HTML with the new HTML using `caption.innerHTML`.

```
// Get all the captions
var captions = document.querySelectorAll('.caption');

// Loop through each caption
captions.forEach(function(caption) {
  // Get the text content of the caption
  var captionText = caption.textContent;

  // Split the text into title and subtitle using the colon separator
  var titleSubtitleArray = captionText.split(':');
  var title = titleSubtitleArray[0];
  var subtitle = titleSubtitleArray[1].trim();

  // Replace the original caption HTML with the new HTML
  caption.innerHTML = '<span class="title">' + title + '</span><span class="subtitle">' + subtitle + '</span>';
});
```